# Looking for Activiti Alfresco Workflow tutorial step by step

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

Where i can find simple tutorial for Activiti Alfresco Workflow (especially with Custom Workflow) ?

I'm new with Alfresco Activiti Worfklow. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have written a tutorial on using the Activiti workflow engine that is embedded in Alfresco 4 that shows how to create custom workflows. It includes everything you need to know from setting up the workflow using the Activiti Eclipse plug-in to defining your workflow content model and wiring up everything in Spring. It includes basic hello world examples as well as a slightly more complex example that incorporates a custom task listener. The tutorial lives [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article-2ed.pdf).

Comment: Updated version lives here: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tutorial but is there a possibility that this can work with the new versions of Alfresco (5.0d) and Activiti (5.17) ?

Comment: I'm working on upgrading the tutorial to work with 5.0.d later this week.

Comment: Activiti can be integrated with the application i am having?

Comment: In case someone is looking for some super quick introduction and setup..I wrote this blog post: www.codecramp.com/activiti-setup-eclipse. It provides working code with two simple processes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe google first? :)

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#10minutetutorial

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html

I think you can figure it out from here on..

Comment: hi thanks matjaz. yes, i did it (google 1st) and still looking. i've already seen your links before, and also i've bought ebook licensed 'activiti in action'. but there is only 1 chapter regarding alfresco topic (still don't have enough information about custom workflow).

Comment: That is a very fine manual, it means that you already kwon what BPM are. Regards,