# Activiti use with CMIS

Tags: alfresco, activiti, cmis

Can any one give me a simple exemple of how to use activiti workflow engin  with CMIS (even a very small user task with activiti and how to use it in CMIS standard)
P.S :I'm working with alfresco

Comment: did you see [Looking for Activiti Alfresco Workflow tutorial step by step ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733182/looking-for-activiti-alfresco-workflow-tutorial-step-by-step)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. The easiest way to use Activiti and CMIS together is to write a Java Delegate class that leverages Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS to work with Alfresco. You might do this if you want to have an Activiti business process that has one or more tasks that involve creating, accessing, or updating content in Alfresco (or any other CMIS repository).

Writing a Java Delegate class is really easy and using OpenCMIS is pretty easy too, so you should have no trouble putting them together.

Here is a video from Alfresco Summit that talks about Java Delegates:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phju1Lru7kI

Here is a link to the Java Delegate documentation:
https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/index.html

And here is a site that documents a variety of CMIS examples:
https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/